# How to reset a spy or mock in jest

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, react-testing-library, spy

I have a function that I have mocked in my test cases file.

```
MyService.getConfigsForEntity = jest.fn().mockReturnValue(
    new Promise(resolve => {
        let response = [];
        resolve(response);
    })
);
```

Now I want all my test cases in that file to use this mock like

```
describe('Should render Component Page', () => {
    it('should call the API', async () => {
        const {container} = render(<MyComp entityName='entity1'/>);
        await wait(() => expect(MyService.getConfigsForEntity).toHaveBeenCalled());
    });
});
```

The only issue is in only one of the test case I want to mock the return value differently.

But all other test cases before and after can use the global mock.

```
describe('Should call API on link click', () => {
    it('should call the API on link click', async () => {
       const spy = jest.spyOn(MyService, 'getConfigsForEntity ').mockReturnValue(
           new Promise(resolve => {
           let response = [{
               "itemName": "Dummy"
           }];
           resolve(response);
        });
        const {container} = render(<MyComp entityName='entity1'/>);
        await wait(() => expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled());
        spy.mockClear();
    });
});
```

The problem is , once I mock the function differently inside one test case , all other test cases after that test case, that are using the global mock , are failing,

But it only works if I put the test case after all other test cases.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can try with `mockRestore()`:

```
beforeEach(() => {
  spy.mockRestore();
});
```

Comment: @StrugglingCoder does this solution worked for you ?

Comment: mockClear work for me with a spy function also in the beforeEach block:

 //fileSaverSpy = jest.spyOn(FileSaver, 'saveAs');
 //fileSaverSpy.mockClear();

Answer (score 1):

have you tried?

```
  beforeEach(() => {
     jest.clearAllMocks();
  })
```